# How to Setup Laravel Database Connection from User Input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For first time setup, I'd like my laravel application to be able to allow the user to specify which database to use as well as which type of database to use. How would I create a form action that would take this information and set it to the laravel's default database connection?

Would I have to create a php script that writes a new `app/config/database.php` file? Or is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Are you going to have a list of pre-defined databases they need to choose from or are you actually going to create new databases for them based on their needs?

Comment: I would assume that they would create the database on their own, and then just pass the application the name of the database and the username+password. I think Wordpress does something like this?

Comment: I would say save the database name to whatever table that has the rest of their information and just use something like `Config::set('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default').'database', Auth::user()->database);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have implement the adapters for each database type you're suggesting e.g. mysql/mongodb/pdo sqlite and put for example in the path /DB/Adapter/ then just list the directory via `scandir` or `opendir`

--edit--
You can also write the info into the database.php in the config file after validating the data. Or (by my opinion better) write it into an non accessible XML/yaml/ini file and then on initiation use `Config::set`